# Get list of divs under mouse position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking for a way to get a list of divs under the mouse when the mouse is over a container div.  Something like:

`$('.container').mouseover(function(e){
  ...getDivsAtThisPoint()...
});`

Kind of like `Document.elementFromPoint()` except "all elements within a specified container from point" (and out of the 'experimental' stage).

Maybe something involving event bubbling through each child div? But I haven't been able to figure out how to make that work.

Comment: [`document.elementsFromPoint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementsFromPoint).

Comment: Are you talking about divs that are all descendents of one another, or divs that aren't connected in the HTML but which have been positioned to overlap via CSS?

Comment: @Xufox: not available in Safari :(

Comment: @nnnnn: any divs that are children of the specified container. In my case they are overlapping via absolute positioning.

Comment: @T3db0t There’s a [polyfill](https://gist.github.com/aniddan/54d5d9e58311b0495a91bf06de661380) using `document.elementFromPoint`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up creating this jQuery extension, adapted from [this link](https://gist.github.com/aniddan/54d5d9e58311b0495a91bf06de661380) and Xufox's comment:

```
(function ($, document, undefined) {
  $.fn.extend({
    /**
     * @param {number} x The x-coordinate of the Point.
     * @param {number} y The y-coordinate of the Point.
     * @param {Element} until (optional) The element at which traversing should stop. Default is document.body
     * @return {jQuery} A set of all elements visible at the given point.
     */
    elementsFromPoint: function(x, y, until) {
      until = this[0];

      var parents = [];
      var current;

      do {
        current = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
        if (current !== until) {
          console.log("current",current);
          parents.push(current);
          current.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
        } else {
          current = false;
        }
      } while (current);

      parents.forEach(function (parent) {
          return parent.style.pointerEvents = 'all';
      });
      return $(parents);
    }
  });
})(jQuery, document);
```

I use it like so:

```
$('.availabilityOverlap').mouseover(function(e){
  console.log($('.availabilityOverlap').elementsFromPoint(e.pageX, e.pageY));
});
```

It produces exactly the output I wanted: an array of jQuery elements up to, but not including, the specified container.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this? And by all elements you mean all descendants and not just the direct descendants of `div.container`?

why not use .find('*') to get all descendants of div.container on mouseover:

```js
$('.container').mouseover(function(e){
    console.log($(this).find('*'))
});
```

```css
.container div {
   padding: 10px;
}

.container div:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #a3fecbef;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <section>001</section>
    </div>
    <div>
        <section>002</section>
    </div>
    <div>
        <section>003</section>
    </div>
    <div>
        <section>004</section>
    </div>
    <div>
        <section>005</section>
    </div>
    <div>
        <section>006</section>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The question clearly states that I need divs that are under the mouse's current position.